# Foundation and jquery Fullcalendar issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

### I've been trying to get this fixed for more than 3 hours now.

can be ignored, jsfiddle bellow
(some sample code, doesn't let me post otherwise)

```
    <div class="row">
        <div id="calendar">

        </div>
    </div>
            <script>
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar();
```

I've made a fiddle of the issue
http://jsfiddle.net/UnL8E/1/

Choose week or day and you should be able to notice the highlight column there doesn't go down on all rows.

I know the issue is due to foundation css, but can't really see why and where.

example of how it should look is
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

if I remove foundation.css it does show properly.

Not sure where is the conflict here.

Looking forward for some help here before I really go crazy :(

Regards.

Comment: I have no good answer but I would guess foundation does something with the tables that doesn't cooperate with the calendar plugin.

If you have the foundation source, try commenting out the table part.

Comment: Indeed, one margin-bottom and backgrounds on table was causing that.

Comment: Yes, was indeed the table css in foundation if I recall right.
RE: one margin-bottom and backgrounds on table

Answer (score 1):

The culprit for me was Foundation's default style of `table { background: #FFFFFF }` which I changed to `transparent` and everything was fixed!